# Data read by fread is longer than what I wrote with fwrite

Tags: c

I made a program that can look for prime numbers. It works fine until it hits a point where the file is suddenly longer than what I wrote with fwrite. Here is the code. I am sorry, it is a bit long, but it is complete and executable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long *loadPrimeNums(char *fileName);
void putPrimeNumsInList(long long *primeNums);
void addIntNode(void);
void initialize(void);
void DestroyIntNodes(void);
void writeInFile(void);
void run(void);

int main () 
{
    initialize();
    putPrimeNumsInList(loadPrimeNums("primeNums"));
    run();
    
    writeInFile();
    DestroyIntNodes();
    _fcloseall();
    return 0;   
}
```

Second file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct longLongNode
{
    long long value;
    struct longLongNode *next;
};

long long *loadPrimeNums(char *fileName);
void putPrimeNumsInList(long long *primeNums);
void addLongLongNode(void);
void initialize(void);
void DestroyIntNodes(void);
void writeInFile(void);
void run(void);

FILE *primeNums_fp;
long long currentOffset;
struct longLongNode *head, *tail, *lastOldPrimeNum;

void run()
{
    struct longLongNode *current;
    current = head;
    
    int isPrime = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            if (currentOffset % current->value == 0)
            {
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
        if (isPrime == 0)
        {
            isPrime = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            addLongLongNode();
        }
        currentOffset++;
        current = head;
    }
}


void writeInFile()
{
    int numberOfNewPrimes = 0;
    long long *newPrimes;
    struct longLongNode *current;
    current = lastOldPrimeNum;
    
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        numberOfNewPrimes++;
        current = current->next;
    }
    
    if (numberOfNewPrimes > 0)
    {
        current = lastOldPrimeNum->next;
        newPrimes = (long long *)malloc(sizeof *newPrimes * numberOfNewPrimes);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfNewPrimes; i++)
        {
            newPrimes[i] = current->value;
            current = current->next;
        }
        fseek(primeNums_fp, 0L, 2);
        fwrite(newPrimes, sizeof *newPrimes, numberOfNewPrimes, primeNums_fp);
        printf("Freeing newPrimes: The array that is used to write the new prime numbers to file.\n");
        free(newPrimes);
    }
}

void initialize()
{
    head = (struct longLongNode *)malloc(sizeof *head);
    head->value = 2;
    head->next = NULL;
    lastOldPrimeNum = head;
}

void addLongLongNode()
{
    struct longLongNode *temp;
    temp = (struct longLongNode *)malloc(sizeof *temp);
    temp->value = currentOffset;
    temp->next = NULL;
    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;
}

long long *loadPrimeNums(char *fileName)
{
    int num;
    long long *ret;
    primeNums_fp = fopen("primeNums", "a+");
    fseek(primeNums_fp, 0L, 2);
    if (ftell(primeNums_fp) != 0)
    {
        if (ftell(primeNums_fp) % sizeof *ret == 0)
        {
            num = ftell(primeNums_fp) / sizeof *ret;
            ret = (long long *)malloc(sizeof *ret * (num + 1));
            rewind(primeNums_fp);
            fread(ret, sizeof *ret, num, primeNums_fp);
            ret[num] = -1;
            return ret;
        }
        else if (ftell(primeNums_fp) != -1)
        {
            printf("ERROR!!! ftell(fp): %d", ftell(primeNums_fp));
            _fcloseall();
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void putPrimeNumsInList(long long *primeNums)
{
    struct longLongNode *current, *temp;
    
    current = head;
    tail = head;
    
    
    if (primeNums != NULL) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; primeNums[i] != -1; i++)
        {
            temp = (struct longLongNode *)malloc(sizeof *temp);
            temp->value = primeNums[i];
            temp->next = NULL;
            current->next = temp;
            current = temp;
        }
        tail = current;
        lastOldPrimeNum = current;
    }
    currentOffset = current->value + 1;
    printf("Freeing primeNums: The array that contains the initially loaded prime numbers of the file.\n");
    free(primeNums);
}

void DestroyIntNodes()
{
    struct longLongNode *current, *next;
    current = head;
    for (int i = 1; current != NULL; i++)
    {
        next = current->next;
        printf("%d: Freeing %d\n", i, current->value);
        free(current);
        current = next;
    }
}
```

What I get after finding 384 prime numbers is an error message that I made myself which shows how big the file is. The file should be divisible by 8, because the prime numbers are stored as `long long` integers, but at some point I got a file size of 3073.

Edit: You need to run the program multiple times for the error to occur. I did not know how to multithread, so I made it so it stops after a 100 iterations. Then the prime numbers it found will be stored in a file which should be divisible by 8, but isn't.

Edit2: At the start, the file does not exist. And I am using Windows 10. I am trying now the suggestion of setting fopen mode "ab+".

Edit3: Solved thanks to @user3121023!!

Comment: What operating system are you using? Is it Microsoft Windows or Linux? I am asking because on the former, there is a big difference between opening a file in text mode and binary mode, whereas on the latter, there is no difference.

Comment: Thank you @user3121023 I think `ab+` solved it!!

Comment: @mkdrive2: That probably means that you are using Microsoft Windows. Am I right?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, I am.

Comment: Always specify `"t"` or `"b"`. MS may default to text mode, and if you write a binary `13` you'll have a problem.

Comment: @mkdrive2: Adding the `b` will cause the file to be opened in binary mode. Otherwise, the file is opened in text mode, which, on Microsoft Windows, causes `\n` to be translated to `\r\n` when writing and `\r\n` to be translated to `\n` while reading. Also, a byte with the value `0x1A` will be interpreted as the end of the file when using text mode, even if it is not the end of the file.

Comment: It may not make a difference in Linux, but if you always specify the mode, it signals your intention to people reading the code (and makes it portable).

Comment: @WeatherVane: According to [§7.21.5.3 ¶3 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p3), adding a `t` will invoke undefined behavior. Therefore, doing as you suggest may make the code not portable.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel in that case the `t` in MSVC is benign: always specify the `b` mode.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel "What operating system are you using? Is it Microsoft Windows or Linux?" --> It is not a OS issue, but a compiler one.  gcc on widows uses the `"\n"`, not `"\r\n"`,.

Comment: @chux: When I use gcc in MinGW on Windows, it produces `\r\n` line endings. Which platform are you referring to? My guess is that you are referring to Cygwin, which is designed to provide POSIX behavior in contrast to the standard behavior on the operating system.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes, compiled gcc via Cygwin on Windows - thus an compiler issue, not an OS one.

Comment: @mkdrive2 Aside: `ftell()` returns a `long`.  Should use `"%ld"` in `printf("ERROR!!! ftell(fp): %d", ftell(primeNums_fp));`